# Cognos Prompt page prompts show/hide using render variable

Tags: javascript

I have struggle to show/hiding prompts in Cognos prompt page. I am using Cognos 10.2.1.

My requirement, prompt page selection is different. I have 3 prompts. After run the report first prompt only need to show. Then after selecting the first prompt value 2nd prompt will be displayed. Like vise 3rd prompt.

Now i am used Boolean variable ParamDisplayValue <> '0'. If its true means its render the 2nd prompt. Like vise another prompt. But here i have to select first prompt only. Second prompt not displayed.

If you have any idea please share me.

Thanks & Regards,
Chandrasekr.

Answer (score 1):

Render variables are only evaluated at time of page render. They are only re-evaluated in three ways:

1. User clicks on a button that is set to 'Reprompt'
2. User selects a value from a prompt that has its 'Auto-Submit' property set to 'Yes' AND required prompts are not yet supplied.
3. JavaScript is fired reprompting the page

Number 1 will work but not provide very good usability as you require the user to click a button each time the page needs refreshed

Number 2 will work if you are working with required prompts. If the prompts are optional the entire prompt page will be submitted when a prompt with 'Auto-Submit' set to 'Yes' is changed. There is a trick you can use involving a hidden prompt that gets around this but it's messy.

Number 3 is the best bet as it gives you the most control. Thankfully, since Cognos 10.2 a documented and supported JavaScript API is provided that makes this rather easy and supported. Here are the steps:

1. Give a name to the prompt* that you want to trigger the reprompt when the value changes.
2. Add a new HTML item to the bottom of your prompt page.
3. Add the following JavaScript as the expression:

```js
var report = cognos.Report.getReport("_THIS_");

var prompt = report.prompt.getControlByName("prompt_name"); //Substitue the prompt name you set in step one for the string "prompt_name"

var currentvalue = prompt.getValues()[0].use;

prompt.setValidator(validatePrompt); //Sets a function to validate the prompt on change

function validatePrompt(values) {
  if (values && values.length > 0 && values[0].use != currentvalue) {
    currentvalue = values[0].use;
    report.sendRequest(cognos.Report.Action.REPROMPT); //Reprompt the page
  }
}
```

The code adds a validation function to the prompt that will refresh the page when the value is changed. The code that sets the initial value and letter checks against this value is used to prevent unnecessary refreshes as Cognos initiates a validation on prompts multiple times behind the scenes. You don't want the page refreshing unless the user actually changes the value of the prompt.

*This prompt should be something other than a text prompt as text prompt validation occurs on every keypress and thus the refresh would be happening for every letter they typed. The technique works best on value prompts such as lists, dropdowns or radio button groups.